# Wso2 CEP - on docker

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

Im trying to build a docker image of Wso2 CEP on a linux VM. 
I failing in the ./build.sh script and I get the following error meassage

> Docker version should be equal to or greater than 1.10.0 to build WSO2 Docker images. Found 17.03.0-ce

[image]

How  can I solve the docker version issue? 
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker version validating logic used in scripts are not compatible with latest docker version.

You can comment the following line in [common/scripts/docker-build.sh file](https://github.com/wso2-attic/dockerfiles/blob/master/common/scripts/docker-build.sh#L204) to skip the validation.

```
# validateDockerVersion "${docker_version}" "${min_required_docker_version}"
```